# "USB Device not recognized" but no USB devices attached

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

As far as I know, no USB devices attached but it's a laptop device maybe a touchpad is connected through USB.

Screenshot of error:

[image: screenshot]

Screenshot of device manager:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The USB hardware and device handling is built into Windows and integrated right in. Windows provides the USB interface.

I have not seen the above message and it appears something has gone wrong with your system.

1. Run a full scan with Windows Defender to check for viruses.
2. Get your manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and check for hardware errors.
3. If no hardware errors, back up your data and then Reset Windows (reinstall Windows) to return to its initial state, update it and restore your data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Device Manager**
2. From the **`View`** menu, select `Devices by connection` and `Show hidden devices`.  [image]
3. Expand the `USB controller` and look for a (most likely) `unknown USB device`.  [image]
4. First thing to try would be to delete the device and allow it to be re-detected. (**`Action`>`Scan for hardware changes`**)
5. Or it could be laptop-specific hardware that nees a driver.
   Sometimes deleting the root hub or host controller forces re-detection of everything & fixes the problem.